# Display a fraction in a dynamically changing plot

Tags: r, plot, plotmath

I'm wondering how I can actually display a *conditional calculation (see below)* I'm using to obtain what I call `GG` in my R codes (see codes below)?

**Details:**

To be precise, I want to display in my plot that `GG` = G1 / G2 (displayed IF `type = 1`) and ELSE `GG` = (G1 / G2 ) * 2 (displayed IF `type == 2`).

For example, if G1 = 1, G2 = 2, what I want to be shown depending on "type" is one of the following:

[image]

**Note:** In the picture above, I used "X 2" out of hurry, but I need an actual *x-like mathematical sign for the multiplication sign*.

Below is my R code:

```
G1 = 1  ## Can be any other number, comes from a function
G2 = 2  ## Can be any other number, comes from a function
type = 1 ## Can be either 1 or 2

plot(1:10,ty="n",ann=F, bty="n")

text( 6, 6, expression(paste("GG = ", ifelse(type==1, frac(G1, G2), frac(G1, G2)*2 ), " = ", 
           G1/G2, sep = "")), col = "red4", cex = 1.6 )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `bquote`, use `.()` to add dynamic values into expression:

```
type = 1
plot(1:10, ty = "n", ann = F, bty = "n")
text(6, 6,
     bquote(paste("GG = ", frac(.(G1), .(G2)),
                  .(ifelse(type == 1, " × 2", "")),
                  " = ", 
                  .(ifelse(type == 1, G1/G2 * 2, G1/G2)), sep = "")),
     col = "red4", cex = 1.6)
```

[image]

**Note:** ASCII code for Multiplication Sign(×) is `Alt 0215`

Answer (score 0):

Awesome @zx8754, very nice.

I misunderstood your question and thought you wanted to print the formula and result so I produced this.

```
plot(1:10,ty="n",ann=F, bty="n")
text( 6, 6, if (type==1) substitute(paste("GG = ", frac(G1, G2)) == list(x), list(x=G1/G2)) else
               substitute(paste("GG = ", frac(G1, G2), " x 2") == list(x), list(x=G1/G2 * 2)), col = "red4", cex = 1.6 )
```

[image]